# The help center does not reflect the new top bar

Tags: bug

I'm not sure if we should wait a bit longer until we are absolutely sure that the new top bar is staying in it's current form (such as the dots in the review drop down) but currently the help center isn't reflecting the new top bar.

Take for example [access review queues](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) which still states:

> These and all other review queues are accessible from the "review"
> link that appears at the top of every page next to your user name

The review link no longer exists and is replaced by an icon.

[Access to moderator tools](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) for example says

> Access these tools by clicking the review link in the top bar, and
> then the Tools link in the header:
>
> [image]

which is currently also outdated.

Comment: I think we should wait just a little bit longer since now we *have* to depend on screenshots (describing an icon in text is... eww) and the icon may well change again soon.

Comment: I must say, I *hate* the topbar nav.  It's not intuitive, and where did the "help" button go?